# Missing class: Class 'bootstrap_mage' is missing

Tags: magento-1.9

We got a message from one of our customer to say they got this error message on our Magento 1.9.3 site when they tried to go to the checkout:

> Missing class: Class 'bootstrap_mage' is missing

Any idea what could be causing this?  I'm trying to get more detail from the customer but this is what I have for now.  We have had about 25 successful orders since this customer reported the issue.  Also I've checked to make sure both of these files exist on our production environment and they do:

`app/bootstrap.php`

`lib/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php`

Anyone have any ideas on what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Class 'bootstrap_mage' is not a default feature, and that infers that its a 3rd party extension or customization.

You might need to search through all of the source code for 'bootstrap_mage'.

Based on the lowercase class name, there are a few issues:

1. The class is most likely being called with `new bootstrap_mage()` instead of the Magento default `Mage::getModel('extension/something')`
2. The autoloader is going to choke on this (except on Windows Platform hosts), so there has to be some addition to the autoloader, or the class is already expected to be loaded.